# Two-Way data binding (ionic / sqlite / angularjs)--NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I'm working on saving, retrieving, editing data using SQLite / ionic / Angularjs.
I saved and retrieved the data successfully. And i'm left with an edit page.
I linked href from display page to an edit page with the hope of populating the edit page with data from the display page, but the binding is not working.
Thanks for your kind assistance:

Display view:

```html
<ion-view view-title="List">

  <ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="TeamCtrl">

    <div class="list list-inset">

      <div class="item item-divider item-royal">
        PERSONAL DETAILS
      </div>
      <div class="item item-input-inset">
        <label class="item item-input item-input-wrapper">First Name :
          <input type="text" ng-model="data.name" required>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="item item-input-inset">
        <label class="item item-input item-input-wrapper">ID  :
          <input type="number" ng-model="data.id" required>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="padding">
        <div class="list">
          <a class="item" ng-repeat="task in Ourdata" href="#/edit/{{task.id}}">
            <h2>{{task.id}}</h2>
            <p>{{task.name}}</p>
            
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="padding">
        <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="createNewTeamMember(data)">
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="padding">
        <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="DisplayMember(data)">
          Display
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The Edit View:

```html
<ion-view view-title="Edit">
  <ion-content ng-controller="TeamCtrl">


    <div class="list list-inset">

      <div class="item item-divider item-royal">
        PERSONAL DETAILS
      </div>
      <div class="item item-input-inset">
        <label class="item item-input item-input-wrapper">First Name :
          <input type="text" ng-model="task.name" required>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="item item-input-inset">
        <label class="item item-input item-input-wrapper">ID  :
          <input type="number" ng-model="task.id" required>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--<div class="padding">
      <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="DisplaySingleMember(RegId)">
        Display
      </button>
    </div>-->
    </div>
  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

The Controller:

```js
.controller('TeamCtrl', function($scope, Team, $state) {
          $scope.team = [];
          $scope.team = null;
          $scope.RegId = $state.params.RegId;
          $scope.updateTeam = function() {
            Team.all().then(function(team){
              $scope.team = team;
            });
          }

          $scope.updateTeam();

          $scope.createNewTeamMember = function(member) {
            console.log("hello");
            Team.add(member);
            $scope.updateTeam();
          };

          $scope.removeMember = function(member) {
            Team.remove(member);
            $scope.updateTeam();
          };

          $scope.editMember = function(origMember, editMember) {
            Team.update(origMember, editMember);
            $scope.updateTeam();
          };

          $scope.DisplayMember = function(member) {
          Team.all(member).then(function(data){  $scope.Ourdata= data;console.log($scope.Ourdata);});
          };

          $scope.DisplaySingleMember = function(RegId) {
            Team.get(RegId).then(function(data){ $scope.task= data;console.log($scope.task);});
          };


  })
```

Comment: Where did you call `DisplaySingleMember` when edit was clicked ?

Comment: Just tested it to make sure it works sir. I called it on the edit page but i later removed. The only thing i need from it is $scope.task= data. Sincerely i donnot know where to put it or call it sir.

Comment: And i would like to point out that i used href but not ng-click sir.

Comment: Also here is the link to the code sir.https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzqArLT5flPEZ19SUEptWmtFZzA/view?usp=sharing